# GIS Tools using Google App Engine's Datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gis

Most GISs require a relational database (MySQL, POSTGIS).

What are some GIS tools that use Google App Engine Datastore.

Comment: What do you mean by represent a poly and line, do you mean to visualize it?

Comment: Yes, the question is a bit vague.  The best way to represent the polygon and line are probably as arrays of PointF objects (in .Net).  What language are you using?  What do you mean by "represent"?  What is the intended outcome?  Lots of details are missing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some prelim research:

Point queries at [GeoModel](http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/)

Areal queries at [GISCloud](http://code.google.com/p/giscloud/)

WFS at [GeoDatastore](http://code.google.com/p/geodatastore/wiki/HowItWorks)

Comment: A bit (lot) outdated but still shown by Google, can we update it?